# What can I do to make my grid clear when I create a new one?

Tags: javascript, css-grid

I'm doing the etch-a-sketch project on The Odin Project and currently creating a grid. The curriculum says I need to allow the user to pick how many squares will be on each side. I had no problem doing this but when the user chooses the number of squares it will not clear the previous grid but only add those new squares to the bottom, basically making a second grid instead of a new one. I would love some suggestions on how to fix this. I will list my code below.

```
const container = document.querySelector('#container');
const grid = {rows:16 , columns:16};
const total = grid.rows * grid.columns;

createGrid(total);

while(document.querySelector('button') !== null) {
document.querySelector('button'.remove());
}

function createGrid(total) {
for( let i = 0; i < total; i++){
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.textContent = `${i+1}`;
    element.classList.add('box');
    element.style.minHeight = '0';
    element.style.minWidth = '0';
    element.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    container.appendChild(element);
    /* This function changes the square background color to black on a mouseover event */
    element.addEventListener('mouseover' , () => {
        element.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
        console.log(element)
    })
}
container.style.setProperty(`grid-template-columns` , `repeat(${grid.columns} , 2fr)`);
```

}

```
function createButton() {
const buttonDiv = document.querySelector('.buttonDiv');
const reset = document.createElement('button');
reset.textContent = 'Reset Grid!';
buttonDiv.appendChild(reset);

reset.addEventListener('click' , () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('element').forEach(e => e.remove());
    let userInput = prompt('Please enter the number of squares for each side (Max: 100)');
    if(userInput > 100 ) {
        alert('You picked more than the max of 100....');
        return;
    }
    rows = userInput;
    columns = userInput;
    createGrid(total);
})
```

}

```
createButton();
```

I'm just not really sure where to start, maybe just a push in the right direction if possible.

Comment: The easy way is to just clear `container` before the loop: `container.innerHTML = ""`

Answer (score 0):

You can use replaceChildren, more information here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceChildren#emptying_a_node

---

That method will remove all the existing nodes and let you add a new set of chidlren if you want. The most basic way of solving your issue would be by adding

```
container.replaceChildren();
```

right before your for loop. Something like this:

```
function createGrid(total) {
  container.replaceChildren();
  for( let i = 0; i < total; i++){
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.textContent = `${i+1}`;
    element.classList.add('box');
    element.style.minHeight = '0';
    element.style.minWidth = '0';
    element.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    container.appendChild(element);
    /* This function changes the square background color to black on a 
    mouseover event */
    element.addEventListener('mouseover' , () => {
        element.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
        console.log(element)
    })
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Haven't gotten it to work quite yet but I'm reading more and it has opened up some new ideas for me, so thank you!